# get the content type 'machine name' by the 'human readable name '

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a content type whose human readable name is *Post your blog*. How can I get the content type machine name by the human readable name?

Is there a function in Drupal 7, or do I have to query the node_type table to get what I want?

Comment: There is no function I know of. The point of machine names is to use them and only convert to human ones on read. Human readable names are **not** unique, so you will have to take care about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily build a query to achieve this. However, as Molot mentioned, you have to handle human readable names that aren't unique.

```
  $machine_name = db_select('node_type', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('type'))
      ->condition('name', 'Basic page')
      ->execute()->fetchField();
```

Comment: @jurgebR thanks for the rely , do i have to write your code like this ?
`$machine_name = db_query('node_type', 'n')
     $machine_name->fields('n', array('type')
     $machine_name->condition('name', 'Post your blog')
     $machine_name->execute()->fetchField();`

Comment: i found some difficult to understand your code , can you please be more specific ? ^^

Comment: My mistake, I've uncorrectly used db_query. Needs to be db_select, updated the answer. Just copy paste and change Basic page to Post your blog.

Comment: :-) My pleasure!

Comment: And for folks that came here looking for the reverse: i.e. how to get the human readable name from the machine name: here's 1) how to get the `$node` object from within `search-result--node.tpl.php`: `$variables['result']['node']` - https://drupal.org/comment/reply/535578/6186406 and 2) with the `$node` object, get the type in machine name form and its human name equivalent: `node_type_get_name($node)` - https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_type_get_name/7

Answer (score 2):

Look at [node_type_get_types](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_get_types/7) for D7 and simply `foreach` looking for `$object->name` as `Post your blog`.

Comment: i've tried  the `node_type_get_types` function , it didn't work for my case